# Run scala code on android devices

Tags: java, android, scala

I'm trying to port [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org) to Android. This framework is partially written in Scala and during the execution of the word count example, an exception is thrown (with many others that I'll not post) as:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lscala/sys/package$;
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.setDefaultCiConfig(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:196)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.LocalFlinkMiniCluster.generateConfiguration(LocalFlinkMiniCluster.scala:58)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.<init>(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:76)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.LocalFlinkMiniCluster.<init>(LocalFlinkMiniCluster.scala:47)
at org.apache.flink.client.LocalExecutor.start(LocalExecutor.java:114)
at org.apache.flink.client.LocalExecutor.executePlan(LocalExecutor.java:173)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.LocalEnvironment.execute(LocalEnvironment.java:90)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:855)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:410)
at hk.ust.symlab.mobiflink.MainActivity$collectActivity.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:86)
at hk.ust.symlab.mobiflink.MainActivity$collectActivity.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:81)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
...
```

With the exceptions it seems that the Android device cannot run scala code (correct me if I'm wrong).

I've found many post about Android and Scala, but they seem more about **write** scala in Android applications to make the code simpler and shorter.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135407/run-scala-on-android) about the topic but isn't helpful.

**So the question is**: how to run scala code on Android devices? Or alternatively: can Android run Scala code?

Comment: Do you have the scala runtime jar file in that app?

Comment: Could you please clarify you question.  The title: "Run scala code on android devices" is not a question.  I also do not see a question in your post.  So it is unclear if you are asking (a) can Android run Scala code, or (b) how do I fix this specific problem.

Comment: @EJK in theory solving the first question solves the second. But anyway I edited the question.

Comment: @Thilo I just added `compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.0-M3'` and now I'm receiving a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes` ... `Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)`

Comment: Found out that the previous error was raised because Flink uses Scala 2.10 (and not 2.12). @Thilo if you answer I'll chose it as the correct one.

Comment: A good entry point for Scala on Android is https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala programs require the Scala runtime library. You need to include that jar file in your application.

This is not specific to Android, but applies to desktop Java as well.